# iwlwifi: Not associated and the session protection is over already

Tags: wifi, intel, iwlwifi

What does this error mean,

> Not associated and the session protection is over already...

I'm getting this in my logs,

```
wlp0s20f3: Connection to AP ee:92:90:14:8a:40 lost
wlp0s20f3: aborting authentication with ee:92:90:14:8a:40 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
wlp0s20f3: authenticate with ee:92:90:14:8a:40
wlp0s20f3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
wlp0s20f3: send auth to ee:92:90:14:8a:40 (try 1/3)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not associated and the session protection is over already...
```

What is "session protection"?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I bought a new router. My laptop (Fedora 37, kernel 6.3.12, intel AX200 WiFi controller) worked smoothly for a couple of days, before it suddenly lost the wifi connection and wouldn't re-connect again (reboot didn't help). All my other devices have no issue, it's just my laptop. The kernel log shows:

```
wpa_supplicant[2317]: wlp110s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Liu" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
kernel: wlp110s0: authentication with 48:5f:08:86:77:46 timed out
kernel: wlp110s0: send auth to 48:5f:08:86:77:46 (try 3/3)
kernel: wlp110s0: Connection to AP 48:5f:08:86:77:46 lost
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:6e:00.0: Not associated and the session protection is over already...
kernel: wlp110s0: send auth to 48:5f:08:86:77:46 (try 2/3)
kernel: wlp110s0: Connection to AP 48:5f:08:86:77:46 lost
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:6e:00.0: Not associated and the session protection is over already...
NetworkManager[12069]: <info>  [1692597573.5168] device (p2p-dev-wlp110s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
kernel: wlp110s0: send auth to 48:5f:08:86:77:46 (try 1/3)
NetworkManager[12069]: <info>  [1692597573.5167] device (wlp110s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
kernel: wlp110s0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
kernel: wlp110s0: authenticate with 48:5f:08:86:77:46
wpa_supplicant[2317]: wlp110s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 48:5f:08:86:77:46 (SSID='Liu' freq=2412 MHz)
```

Tried to boot into Windows 10 and the wifi worked again. So it's not a hardware issue. Also tried to [disable powersave in NetworkManager](https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55), still not working.

Finally I tried to **disable WPA3 authentication in my router**, and it works! Originally it was WPA2/WPA3 mixed, now after changing to WPA/WPA2 mixed mode, my laptop is able to connect again.

Not sure why it had worked before but suddenly failed today. I suspect it's a bug with iwl driver or wpa_supplicant.